# Validating EditTextPreference on Android

Tags: android, validation, edittextpreference

I have read the many answers on this question but my question is asking where I place the code. I am looking to validate that a number is greater than 100 in the `EditTextPreference`. This is the code I use to populate the preferences:

```java
public class SettingsFrag extends PreferenceFragment{
          
  //Override onCreate so that the code will run when the activity is started.
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){        
          //Call to the super class.
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          
          //add the preferences from the XML file.
          addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  }

}
```

Is it in here I add the validation or would I have to create another class?

preferences.xml:

```xml
<EditTextPreference             
    android:key="geofence_range"             
    android:title="Geofence Size"             
    android:defaultValue="500"     
    android:inputType="number"
    android:summary="Geofence Size Around User Location"             
    android:dialogTitle="Enter Size (meters):" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` for `EditTextPreference` after `addPreferencesFromResource` to validate data input for User:

```
EditTextPreference edit_Pref = (EditTextPreference) 
                    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("geofence_range");
   edit_Pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

     @Override
      public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
          // put validation here..
            if(<validation pass>){
              return true;
            }else{
              return false;
             }
       }
    });
```

Comment: works for me but i set the listener in onCreatePreferences

Answer (score 12):

*Note:* This answer is based on the **deprecated** [`android.preference.EditTextPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference).

---

Huh. Another one of those things that should be so darned easy in Android but isn't. Other answers just silently prevent writing back the result to preferences, which seems a bit shoddy. (Showing toast is less shoddy, but is still shoddy).

You'll need a custom preference to do this. Customize `onValidate` to suit your needs.

```
package com.two_play.extensions;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ValidatingEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {
    public ValidatingEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public ValidatingEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public ValidatingEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ValidatingEditTextPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
        super.showDialog(state);
        AlertDialog dlg = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
        View positiveButton = dlg.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        getEditText().setError(null);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPositiveButtonClicked(v);
            }
        });
    }

    private void onPositiveButtonClicked(View v) {
        String errorMessage = onValidate(getEditText().getText().toString());
        if (errorMessage == null)
        {
            getEditText().setError(null);
            onClick(getDialog(),DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        } else {
            getEditText().setError(errorMessage);
            return; // return WITHOUT dismissing the dialog.
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called to validate contents of the edit text.
     *
     * Return null to indicate success, or return a validation error message to display on the edit text.
     *
     * @param text The text to validate.
     * @return An error message, or null if the value passes validation.
     */
    public String onValidate(String text)
    {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(text);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            return getContext().getString(R.string.error_invalid_number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find the showDialog method in the EditTextPreference class. Please help!

Comment: @Sundaravel I believe you are using the new [`androidx.preference:preference` library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference). The `showDialog` method is no longer exposed as `public` in the `EditTextPreference`. The answer above refers to the **deprecated** [`android.preference.EditTextPreference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference).

Answer (score 3):

It seems more elegant to me to disable the "OK" button instead of allowing the user to press it but then discard their input and show the error. `getDialog` seems to be gone in `androidx.preference`, but this seems to work for me instead:

```
final EditTextPreference p = new EditTextPreference(context);
p.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBindEditText(@NonNull final EditText editText) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String validationError;
                try {
                    // ... insert your validation logic here, throw on failure ...
                    validationError = null; // All OK!
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    validationError = e.getMessage();
                }
                editText.setError(validationError);
                editText.getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.button1)
                        .setEnabled(validationError == null);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Kotlin implementation for [`androidx.preference.*`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference) based on [Vladimir Panteleev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59297100/356895):

```
class CustomPreference : EditTextPreference {


    // ...

    private fun applyValidation() = setOnBindEditTextListener { editText ->
        editText.doAfterTextChanged { editable ->
            requireNotNull(editable)
            // TODO Add validation magic here.
            editText.error = if (criteria.isValid()) {
                null // Everything is fine.
            } else {
                if (criteria.getErrorMessage() == null) "Unknown validation error"
                else resources.getString(criteria.getErrorMessage())
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The handy `doAfterTextChanged` extension is part of the [`androidx.core:core-ktx` library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core).